# Facebook like button fails in QA environment

Tags: unit-testing, dns, communication, facebook-like

We've set up a test page on our QA site to do testing on both the Facebook "Like" button and the "Tweet this" button. To do this, we password protected the site (except for the page in question), opened up ports 80 and 443? (I think) and set up a public DNS that points to the page.

Here's the test page:
http://qa.asme.org/kb/news---articles/articles/bioengineering/the-artificial-pancreas-project

The button shows a count, but the link doesn't show up on the Facebook feed. What else do we need to do so that we can run a successful test on the button?

Comment: I should also say that we have run successful tests on our sandbox. It was the move over to the testing QA that caused all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). Put the appropriate tags in your page markup. The 'og:url' tag is what you're looking for.

Good luck!